# how can i upload images to cloudinary server using multer middleware after all validation the from req.body using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, cloudinary

hey i want that the image should upload after passing through all the validation logic gets over then it should upload the images to the server but i'm using multer middleware here and using multer middle ware how can i implement it so that i uploads images to the cloudinary server after all the validation gets finished.

#### my middleware

```
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary");
const cloudinaryStorage = require("multer-storage-cloudinary");

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: "*********",
  api_key: "*************",
  api_secret: "*************"
});

exports.cloudinaryStorage = cloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary,
  folder: "game_zone",
  allowedFormats: ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gid", "pdf"],
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname); // The file on cloudinary would have the same name as the original file name
  }
});
```

### schema model

```
const gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  img: [
    {
      type: String,
      default: "default"
    }
  ],
  categories: [
    {
      type: String
    }
  ]
});
```

### My Route

```
router.post("/", upload.array("gameImage", 5), async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

game = new Game(gameData);
  const result = await game.save();
  res.json({
    result: result
  });
});
```

Write now its working fine but not in the corrent way i want to be.
Can you suggest how should i change my implementation here.

Answer (score 1):

`cloudinarystorage` is a constructor. Initialize it as follows:

```
exports.cloudinaryStorage = new cloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary,
  folder: "game_zone",
  allowedFormats: ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gid", "pdf"],
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname); // The file on cloudinary would have the same name as the original file name
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the cloudinary upload widget. it can take care of the validation for you (checking the format) and when getting the response you can save it in your database.
You can read more about it here:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/embed_widgets_players#upload_widget